# Pandas don't merge on empty column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the 2 files:

File 1:

```
website,company_name,uuid
yahoo.com,Yahoo,1111
facebook.com,Facebook,2222
cisco.com,Cisco Inc,3333
,Oasis,4444
google.com,Google Inc,5555
```

File 2:

```
company_url,company_name
facebook.com,
google.com,Google
,Netflix
,Pandas
```

My script needs to match website or company name and generate an output like this:

```
company_url,company_name,uuid
facebook.com,,2222
google.com,google,5555
,netflix,
,pandas,
```

Currently is doing the following:

```
company_url,company_name,uuid
facebook.com,,2222.0
google.com,google,5555.0
,netflix,4444
,pandas,4444
```

Seems to be matching on the empty website in File1.

Code:

```
  merge_tld = competitor_companies.merge(
      companies[['tld', 'uuid']], on='tld', how='left')      
  # Extracts UUID for company name matches.
  competitor_companies = competitor_companies.merge(
      companies[['company_name', 'uuid']], on='company_name', how='left')
  # Combines dataframes.
  competitor_companies['uuid'] = competitor_companies['uuid'].combine_first(
      merge_tld['uuid'])
```

Function:

```
def MatchCompetitorCompanies(
    companies: pandas.Dataframe,
    competitor_companies: pandas.Dataframe) -> Optional[Sequence[str]]:
  """Find Competitor companies in companies dataframe and generate a new list.

  Args:
    companies: A dataframe with company information from CSV file.
    competitor_companies: A dataframe with Competitor information from CSV file.

  Returns:
    A sequence of matched companies and their UUID.

  Raises:
    ValueError: No companies found.
  """

  if _IsEmpty(companies):
    raise ValueError('No companies found')
  # Clean up empty fields.
  companies = companies.fillna('')
  logging.info('Found: %d records.', len(competitor_companies))
  competitor_companies = competitor_companies.fillna('')
  # Rename column to TLD to compare matching companies.
  companies.rename(columns={'website': 'tld'}, inplace=True)
  logging.info('Cleaning up company name.')
  companies.company_name = companies.company_name.apply(_NormalizeText)
  competitor_companies.company_name = competitor_companies.company_name.apply(
      _NormalizeText)
  # Rename column to TLD since Competitor already contains TLD in company_url.
  competitor_companies.rename(columns={'company_url': 'tld'}, inplace=True)      
  logging.info('Extracting UUID')
  merge_tld = competitor_companies.merge(
      companies[['tld', 'uuid']], on='tld', how='left')      
  # Extracts UUID for company name matches.
  competitor_companies = competitor_companies.merge(
      companies[['company_name', 'uuid']], on='company_name', how='left')
  # Combines dataframes.
  competitor_companies['uuid'] = competitor_companies['uuid'].combine_first(
      merge_tld['uuid'])
  match_companies = len(
      competitor_companies[competitor_companies['uuid'].notnull()])
  total_companies = len(competitor_companies)
  logging.info('Results found: %d out of %d', match_companies, total_companies)
  competitor_companies.rename(columns={'tld': 'company_url'}, inplace=True)
  return competitor_companies
```

I used this trick:

```
companies = companies.fillna(' ')
```

But looking to see if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one hand, merging `df1` and `df2` on key `'website'`/`'company_url'` (purpose: extract `'company_url'`(complete) and `'uuid'`(partial) information)

```
df3 = (df1
       .merge(df2, left_on='website', right_on='company_url', how='right')
       .drop(['website', 'company_name_x'], axis=1)
       )
df3 = (df3
       .loc[~(df3.company_url.isnull())]
       .reset_index(drop=True)
       .rename(columns={'company_name_y': 'company_name'})
      )
```

`df3`:

```
   uuid   company_url company_name
0  2222  facebook.com          NaN
1  5555    google.com       Google
```

---

On the other hand, merging `df1` and `df2` on  key `'company_name'` (purpose: extract the other `'uuid'` (partial) information which is not necessary in this toy example)

```
df4 = (df1
       .merge(df2, on='company_name', how='right')
       .drop(['website', 'company_url'], axis=1)
       )
df4 = (df4
       .loc[~df4.company_name.isnull()]
       .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

`df4`:

```
  company_name  uuid
0       Google   NaN
1      Netflix   NaN
2       Pandas   NaN
```

---

Merging `df3` and `df4` where `'company_name`' is NOT null, and then further append `df4` to the merged dataframe where `'company_name'` IS null

```
df5 = (df3
       .loc[~df3.company_name.isnull()]
       .merge(df4, on='company_name', how='right')
       )
df5['uuid'] = df5['uuid_x'].fillna(df5['uuid_y'])
df5 = (df5
       .drop(['uuid_x', 'uuid_y'], axis=1)
       .append(df3.loc[df3.company_name.isnull()], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
       .fillna("")
       )
df5['company_name'] = df5.company_name.str.lower()
```

`df5`:

```
  company_name   company_url  uuid
0       google    google.com  5555
1      netflix                    
2       pandas                    
3               facebook.com  2222
```

Hope this helps.